# Objective-C CALayer UIView real rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation, calayer, transformation

I'm trying to rotate a UIView object like shown on the image below
http://i.piccy.info/i7/f8ff7fe488c7c492e6ff6a689bc9cdeb/1-5-2127/60800682/rotation.png

I'm trying to use the CALayer's transform but I get something like this:
http://i.piccy.info/i7/bbb672b058fdfdd251cc90f1ce2b9c1f/1-5-2128/9488743/rotate2.png

Comment: How do you do the transform? I have to say I didn't fully understand the picture, but it seems your scaling instead of rotating.

Comment: myLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI/2.8, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

Comment: 2.8 after the M_PI is just for example.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately my view is scaling instead of rotating :(

Comment: Well I think you should rotate around the Z axis (0,0,1) instead of the X axis (1,0,0). Try that.

Comment: I've tested. the x axis is the axis what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to title the view backwards (into the screen) an should be able to achieve it something like this:

```
float distance = 50;

CATransform3D basicTrans = CATransform3DIdentity;
basicTrans.m34 = 1.0 / -distance;
view.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(basicTrans, M_PI_4, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

To achieve this effect you need to manipulate one of the transformation values directly (m34). The lower `distance` gets, the stronger the effect gets. Then you can do the rotation transformation around the x axis (to tilt), in this case PI/4 or 45 degrees. You can calculate arbitrary values pi using `degrees * M_PI / 180.0`.

Comment: When view rotates it's height is changing. How can I calculate M_PI value if I have fixed new (after rotation) height

Comment: I think trigonometry gives us: `angle = M_PI_4 - asin(newHeight / height)` where `newHeight` should be smaller than `height` but greater than zero.